# typecasting in c between data types string and unsigned long

Tags: c, gcc4

I am using 64 bit gcc compiler on a intel machine to compile following code

```
void main(void) {
    unsigned long L = 1, R = "123";
    printf("%s %lu %lu", "1st",L, R);
    printf("%s %d %s", "2nd", L, R);
}
```

I get following output

> 1st, 1, 4205913
>
> 2nd, 1, 123

my confusion is that when I take %lu what is this number 4205913 while when I take %s "123" is printed correctly.

Comment: it's just undefined behavior. **Turn on compiler warnings.**

Comment: `unsigned long L = 1, R = "123";` is not a valid declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `123` gets printed correctly is a coincidence: it happens that in your architecture an address can fit into `unsigned long`. This is by no means a guarantee, so what you see is undefined behavior that simply "went your way".

The standard defines an integral type `uintptr_t` that is guaranteed to be capable of holding a pointer, though. Using this type with appropriate casting would let you store a pointer in a non-pointer variable, and avoid undefined behavior.